# Using Attributes inspector instead of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am making an app in Xcode where I'm using UI Storyboard format. I usually use attribute inspector instead of ViewController to add buttons, UIImageView, UIText, UILabel; to resize them and to add constraints (except changing cornerRadius). I try to do minimum coding as possible as I feel comfortable using my trackpad more. My question is, after completing my app and submitting it to Apple for review, will there be any complications in approval if they see that I'm using attribute inspector for altering various UI elements and not using ViewController? As I'm using attribute inspector, most of my buttons are not linked to view controller as they are just to change to different ViewController. Will this also affect?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes inspector in storyboards is there to be used. App review isn't going to care one way or another about that.

Comment: Thank you! and what about the image? In the assests library, I have used images and all of them are 1x. Do I need to have 2x and 3x too? My app is running fine on newer iPhones with 1x image size

Comment: It will look pretty bad if you're only using 1x images, but I don't know if app review will care.

Comment: I guess then I need to add 2x and 3x images too. One more question. Will using 2x and 3x images change it's fill in a button? will the image distort? I'm using several images as background of the buttons.

Comment: If the images are sized properly (e.g. a 2x one is twice the size of the 1x one) it will be fine

Comment: And if by any chance the image gets distorted, how do I change it to Aspect fill? While using UIImageview, there’s and option to choose how the image fills the space in attribute inspector but while choosing an image as a “background” of Button, I cannot find an option to do the same.

Comment: You need to ask these as separate questions (or search for them or try things out first), a long conversation in comments does no good for anybody